# SSD Vertex 3 RAID 0 performance over time

Tags: ssd, hardware-raid, vertex-3

I want to set up 2x vertex 3 240gb in a raid0. Will performance degrade over time? Is there a solution?

OS agnostic please - if the hardware supports something a driver can be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the lacking TRIM support for RAID, there might be a performance degrade over time. However, Intel announced that they will support it with the upcoming versions of their drivers as of version 11.5. (Only for RAID 0, though)

Nevertheless, with two Vertex3s in RAID 0, you probably won't even notice a performance degradation.
So take the step and enjoy the transfer rate madness.

Comment: Do you mean a firmware update for the raid controller?

Comment: @kisplit no, I mean the Intel RST raid driver for windows.